# Is there a way i can put Windows 10 in compatibility mode to try and run older software?

Tags: windows, compatibility

Ive got an old c. 2006 vintage Windows .exe programme i need to run in order to connect and configure the processor on a piece of electrical hardware.

I just tried to install the .exe on my windows 10 machine, but the installer wizard its says the operating system is not adequate for running this software.

Is there a way i can put Windows 10 in compatibility mode to try and enable it to run the software ?

Comment: At the very least you could run a VM with an earlier vintage of Windows

Comment: What does your [research](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/15078/windows-make-older-programs-compatible) indicate?  If the application is a 16-bit application, and you are running a 64-bit application, then the only way to run the application is to use a VM which runs a 32-bit version of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

**If it is a 32-bit program**:

Run the Compatibility Troubleshooter (right click > Properties > Compatibility). If it does not help, try setting it to run under "Windows XP Service Pack 3".

**If it is a 16-bit program**:

1. Try running it on 32-bit Windows 7.

or

2. Install Windows XP as shown in [this article from MakeUseOf](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/download-windows-xp-for-free-and-legally-straight-from-microsoft-si/) (too large to show in this answer). This will also run your program in a virtual machine, which, depending on the program, may not be ideal.